# How to connect server from client in Heroku using IP address

Tags: python, heroku

I am developing one application using heroku, but struggling with one issue.
In this application, I have 2 dynos (one is for server, and the other is for client).
Since I want to get some data from server, my client needs to know IP address of the server(dyno).
Now I am trying to use Fixie and QuotaGuard Static,
They tell me an IP address, but I can not connect to the server using these IP address.

Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to have two dynos communicate directly over a socket connection. Unfortunately, you can't easily do that; that runs counter to the ethos of Heroku and 12-factor application design (http://12factor.net), which specifies that processes should be isolated from each other, and that communication be via "network attached services". That second point may seem like a nuance, but it affects how the dynos discover the other services (via injected environment variables).

There are many reasons for this constraint, not the least of which is the fact that "dynos", as a unit of compute, may be scaled, migrated to different physical servers, etc., many times over an application's lifecycle. Trying to connect to a socket on a dyno reliably would actually get pretty complicated (selecting the right one if multiple are running, renegotiating connections after scaling/migration events, etc.). Remember - even if you are never going to call `heroku ps:scale client=2`, Heroku doesn't know that and, as a platform, it is designed to assume that you will.

The solution is to use an intermediate service like Redis to facilitate the inter-process communication via a framework like Python RQ or similar.

Alternatively, treat the two dynos as separate applications - then you can connect from one to the other via HTTP using the publicly available DNS entry for that application. Note - in that case, it would still be possible to share a database if that's required.

Hope that helps.